# How does Arbitrary Coordinate System in QGIS work?

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo, qgis-2, autocad

I have got the drill hole data, which needs to be geo-referenced based on non-earth coordinates system (with no datum, ellipsoid information defining through Custom CRS). Could any one explained me how it works. The output result, I expect here is like the one Non-earth Coordinate system in MapInfo, and Arbitary coordinate system in Autocad??